# php min() array is returing wrong from foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am calculating and getting result and array from a function in a foreach loop and do min() or max() on that result but the result is wrong. Can someone explain to me why? Thanks

```
function subtract($a, $b){
    $c=$b-$a;
    return $c. ',';
    }
    $r=3;
$numbers = array(12, 11, 6, 9, 15);

foreach ($numbers as $index=>$value) {
    $deductions[]=array(subtract($r, $value));
    $minimum=min($deductions);
}
print_r($minimum);
```

I get 12 instead of 3 in this case.

Comment: Just maybe, because you have a `,` in your return value! (BTW: Your code in short: `$numbers = [12, 11, 6, 9, 15];
  $r = 3;
  
  echo min(array_map(function($v)use($r){
   return $v - $r;
  }, $numbers));`)

Comment: The coma was indeed the problem. I thought the coma was just called at compile time to display and was not actually in the array. Thank you for the quick answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
function subtract($a, $b){
    $c=$b-$a;
    return $c;
    }
    $r=3;
$numbers = array(12, 11, 6, 9, 15);

foreach ($numbers as $index=>$value) {
    $deductions[]=array(subtract($r, $value));
    $minimum=min($deductions);
}
echo min($minimum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` as [Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823761/php-min-array-is-returing-wrong-from-foreach#comment49693291_30823761) already showed the way along with the `array_map`

```
$r=3;
$numbers = array(12, 11, 6, 9, 15);
array_walk($numbers,function($v,$k) use(&$result,$r){ $result[$k] = $v-$r;});
print_r(min($result));
```